# R dplyr adds repeated values in full-join

Tags: r, join, dplyr, outer-join

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891637/avoid-repeated-values-in-a-join) question but in R. Full-Join adds repeated values under certain circumstances, namely one table has a repeated value in the "by" column and the other table doesn't.

```
> df1 = data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,3), B=letters[1:4])
> df2 = data.frame(A=c(2,3,3,3), C=LETTERS[1:4])
> full_join(df1, df2, by="A") %>% arrange(A) %>% select(A,B,C)
  A B    C
1 1 a <NA>
2 2 b    A
3 2 c    A
4 3 d    B
5 3 d    C
6 3 d    D
```

Here is an application where it is a nasty problem. I have two ledgers with transactions by date. Each account has dates with multiple transactions. If I try to combined the ledgers they get completely messed up.

```
acct1 = data.frame(
  Date=as.Date(c("2019/1/1", "2019/1/2", "2019/1/2", "2019/1/3")), 
  Amount=c(10, -20, -1, 25)
  )
acct1
#>         Date Amount
#> 1 2019-01-01     10
#> 2 2019-01-02    -20
#> 3 2019-01-02     -1
#> 4 2019-01-03     25

acct2 = data.frame(
  Date=as.Date(c("2019/1/2", "2019/1/3", "2019/1/3", "2019/1/3")), 
  Amount=c(7, 0, -7, 0)
  )
acct2
#>         Date Amount
#> 1 2019-01-02      7
#> 2 2019-01-03      0
#> 3 2019-01-03     -7
#> 4 2019-01-03      0

dplyr::full_join(acct1, acct2, by="Date", suffix=c(".ACCT1", ".ACCT2"))
#>         Date Amount.ACCT1 Amount.ACCT2
#> 1 2019-01-01           10           NA
#> 2 2019-01-02          -20            7
#> 3 2019-01-02           -1            7
#> 4 2019-01-03           25            0
#> 5 2019-01-03           25           -7
#> 6 2019-01-03           25            0
```

Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.3.0)

### Edit

I just found [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-joins-dealing-with-multiple-matches-duplicates-in-key-column/14528) question and it may have a solution.

**Works**

```
acct1 = data.frame(
  Date=as.Date(c("2019/1/1", "2019/1/2", "2019/1/2", "2019/1/3")), 
  Amount=c(10, -20, -1, 25)
  )
acct1 = acct1 %>% mutate(rownum=row_number())
#> Error in acct1 %>% mutate(rownum = row_number()): could not find function "%>%"
acct1
#>         Date Amount
#> 1 2019-01-01     10
#> 2 2019-01-02    -20
#> 3 2019-01-02     -1
#> 4 2019-01-03     25

acct2 = data.frame(
  Date=as.Date(c("2019/1/2", "2019/1/3", "2019/1/3", "2019/1/3")), 
  Amount=c(7, 0, -7, 0)
  )
acct2 = acct2 %>% mutate(rownum=row_number())
#> Error in acct2 %>% mutate(rownum = row_number()): could not find function "%>%"
acct2
#>         Date Amount
#> 1 2019-01-02      7
#> 2 2019-01-03      0
#> 3 2019-01-03     -7
#> 4 2019-01-03      0

dplyr::full_join(acct1, acct2, by=c("rownum", "Date"), suffix=c(".ACCT1", ".ACCT2")) %>% 
  select(-rownum) %>% 
  arrange(Date)
#>         Date Amount.ACCT1 Amount.ACCT2
#> 1 2019-01-01           10           NA
#> 2 2019-01-02          -20           NA
#> 3 2019-01-02           -1           NA
#> 4 2019-01-02           NA            7
#> 5 2019-01-03           25            0
#> 6 2019-01-03           NA            0
#> 7 2019-01-03           NA           -7
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? What is the desired output you are after? It doesn't sound like a join is appropriate here at all.

Comment: To put it another way, this is exactly the way full joins are supposed to work, so probably you don't want a full join. Maybe you're looking for something more like `bind_rows()` and possibly creating a grouping variable to distinguish between rows from the two original data frames?

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry. I was assuming it was obvious that the desired output would be that I don't end up with spurious transactions in either of the accounts. This would make me a very bad accountant.

Comment: So how do you decide which values go in which columns and on which rows? I agree with @joran that maybe you are looking for a bind type operation rather than a merge/join. But seeing the desired output for the sample input would make that more clear.

Comment: Specifically, it sort of sounds like you want something more like `bind_rows(acct1 = acct1,acct2 = acct2,.id = "acct")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from my earlier [non-SO answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-joins-dealing-with-multiple-matches-duplicates-in-key-column/14528) referenced in OP:

```
full_join(acct1 %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(id = row_number()),
          acct2 %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(id = row_number()),
          by = c("id", "Date")) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Date, id, acct1 = Amount.x, acct2 = Amount.y)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Date          id acct1 acct2
  <date>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-01     1    10    NA
2 2019-01-02     1   -20     7
3 2019-01-02     2    -1    NA
4 2019-01-03     1    25     0
5 2019-01-03     2    NA    -7
6 2019-01-03     3    NA     0
```

Comment: Yes! This is even better than what I added.

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be more than 1 transaction per day, a list is more natural than a vector.  Example:

```
acct1 <- acct1 %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarize(Amount = list(Amount))
acct2 <- acct2 %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarize(Amount = list(Amount))

dplyr::full_join(acct1, acct2, by="Date", suffix=c(".ACCT1", ".ACCT2")) %>% as.data.frame

        Date Amount.ACCT1 Amount.ACCT2
1 2019-01-01           10         NULL
2 2019-01-02      -20, -1            7
3 2019-01-03           25     0, -7, 0
```

Using this approach, you don't get duplicated transactions.

Comment: But UGH!! I don't have transactions on rows anymore.

Comment: Then do an rbind, and have `acct` as another column.

Comment: `rbind` is not tidy.

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows` then.